# req.user undefined despite successful signup with Passport and Express Session on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js

## The Problem

I am setting up my NodeJS & Express App, using Passport for authentication with Google Sign In and Facebook Login. Everything works very well when working on localhost, but when I deploy my app (to Vercel) I can't make the sessions work.

The signin process works very well, and I can see the user information attached to `req.session`, and `req.user` contains all user information.

However, right after that, when calling any route, `req.user` is `undefined`

## The code

```
//Setting up the app
const express = require('express');
//const https = require('https');

//Bodyparser to handle JSON
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//Mongoose to connect to MongoDB
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//To handle environments
const keys = require('./keys')

//To handle user sessions
var session = require("express-session");
var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);


//Passport to hangle Google Sign In
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

//Authentication: serialize and deserialize user
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log(`serialize: user:${user}`); 
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    console.log(`deserialize user:${user}`)
    done(err, user);
  });
});

//Authentication: Google Sign In
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: keys.GOOGLE_CLIENTID,
    clientSecret: keys.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    callbackURL: keys.URL_GOOGLE_CALLBACK
  },
  function callback(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick( ()=> {
        User.findOne({'googleId': profile.id}, (err,user)=> {
            if(err)
                return done(err,false);
            if(user){
                return done(null, user);
            }
            else{
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.googleId = profile.id;
                newUser.googleToken = accessToken;
                newUser.firstName  = profile.name.givenName;
                newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                newUser.authType = "Google";
                newUser.image = profile.photos[0].value;

                newUser.save((err)=> {
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
      });
  }
));

//Importing the models used
const Country = require('./models/country');
const Place = require('./models/place');
const User = require('./models/user');
const Trip = require('./models/trip');

//Starting the app
const app = express();

//Using body parser as global middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

//Using cookie bodyParser
app.use(require('cookie-parser')('keyboard cat'))

//Using Cors for routes
//app.use(cors())

//Store for sessions
var storeSessions = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: keys.URI_MONGO,
  collection: 'sessions'
});

// Catch errors
storeSessions.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});

//Added but not sure if useful
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true}));


app.set('trust proxy', 1);

//Setting up a session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  proxy: true,
  store: storeSessions,
  cookie : {
    maxAge: 2419200000
  }
}));

//Using passport for authentication
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Solving CORS issues

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:8080', 'mywebsite.com'];
  let origin = req.headers.origin;
  if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  }
  //res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});



//Connection to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(keys.URI_MONGO, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log('Connection successful!'))
  .catch((error) => { console.error(error); });



//The API call from the Google sign in button
app.get('/authgoogle',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));

//Callback from Google Sign in
app.get('/authgoogleredirect', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('google', {
      scope : ['profile', 'email']
    }, function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect(keys.URL_SIGN_IN); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      req.session.user = req.user;
      req.session.save(function(){
        console.log(`req.session.user in callback: ${req.session.user}`)
        console.log(`req.session in callback: ${JSON.stringify(req.session)}`)
        res.redirect(keys.URL_LOGGED_IN);
      });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});



//Middleware to check if user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  console.log(`req.session in isloggedin: ${JSON.stringify(req.session)}`);
  console.log(`req.user in isloggedin: ${JSON.stringify(req.user)}`);
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  } else {
    data = {
      "redirect": true,
      "url": keys.URL_SIGN_IN
    }
    res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
}


//--------------------USERS------------------------
//Getting the currently logged in user
app.get('/getcurrentuser', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(req.user);
});
```

## What works and what does not

The google sign in works well, and `passport.serialize` and `passport.deserialize` work well, I can see the user object.

When I try to reach GET /getcurrentuser (call on all pages), I don't get the req.user object and `isAuthenticated()` always returns `false`.

These are the logs of the middleware isloggedin :
`req.session in isloggedin: {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":2419200000,"expires":"2020-08-07T12:09:54.220Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}`
`req.user in isloggedin: undefined`

The sessions are correctly saved in the session collection in mongoDB.

Serialize and deserialize don't seem to be called after sign in, not sure if that's normal.

## What I tried

I read plenty of answers to similar problems but none seem to work:

- **order of initialization of passport and express session**: it should be correct
- **proxy**: added but did not change anything
- **credentials**: include has always been included in my front end fetch call
- **cookie.secure: false**: turned it on and off, without success
- **cookie session** tried to use it instead of express session, without success

It must be something stupid but I can't seem to find it...
What troubles me is why would this work on localhost?

Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: Edited my initial comment with new problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, if anyone comes across this exact issue, I finally solved it:

`req.user` always came as `undefined`, because my front end and back end have different domain names (I'm using the free heroku tier) therefore **the cookie was considered third-party, blocked by Google Chrome and never sent to my express app**!

As soon as I disabled third-party cookie blocking in Chrome settings the session became persistent!

The passport and session configurations were correct all along...

Thanks @abhinav for your help and time :)

Answer (score 0):

Passport has its own session handling code embedded in its library, if you want to store your passport login user to session-database you can do

```
router.get("/redirect", passport.authenticate('google',{failureRedirect:'/fail',successRedirect:'/success'}, (req,res)=>{
   req.session.user = req.user;
});
```

and keeping your remaining code same as you have done, this will save your session in the database

Comment: Thanks for your help @abhinav ! I tried to change the redirect route to what you described, but this time I'm blocked by CORS policy (I'll dig a bit deeper into this issue).
However, you seem to indicate that there is another way to get the user info? I would prefer using req.user as is mentioned on the documentation, but it is empty, that's why I tried to get this information in req.session (I hope I'm making myself clear).

Comment: if you are using axios for fetching the data then you must do it like this `axios.get('url',{withCredentials:true}`) it is necessary to include this, and add this your server code ``res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'frontend_url'`) .

Comment: I'm not using Axios, but I've always set ```withCredentials:true``` in my fetch request.
And ```res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'frontend_url'`)``` is also set :/
If it's a matter of CORS it would then explain why the issue does not occur on localhost!

Comment: Note: the exact CORS message is the following:
``` Access to fetch at '**backend/getcurrentuser**' from origin '**frontend**' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.```
Should I understand it is back end problem? Weird because i never set the headers to '*'

Comment: yes it is correct, when you use this (`Accesss-Control-Allow-Crendentials`,true) then you should have single frontend link in allow origin header and not array of values, try to give a single link in allow-origin header, it is a mechanism to save from csrf attack

Comment: It changed it to what you suggested and the message is not there anymore :) However I have a new one instead: ```Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.``` So I tried to add a rule for OPTIONS (```res.status(200).send();```) but I can't make it to work. I'll keep looking. Again, thanks for your time @abhinav!

Comment: **New update**: I suspected that the CORS issues were coming from Vercel (it is known to trigger issues) so I deployed my app to Heroku. I have no cors issues anymore, but unfortunately ```req.user``` is still ```undefined``` and ```req.session``` does not contain user information.

Comment: To be precise, the error is ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of null```

Comment: i am having similar issue. Backend is on heroku, frontend is on netlify. The application running locally does not work when deployed. I am using passport js. req.user comes undefined

Comment: I am facing same problem, pls how did you resolve this? @flob

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure, it was 2 years ago and I haven't coded since then. 
But from what I remember it was due to different domain names between my frontend and API. As soon as I moved to the paid Heroku tier and could use a subdomain of my domain name, it started to work well!
@Paulliano

Comment: Oh okay thanks, I already have my domain and subdomain set, but it still didnot work  @flob

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that worked for me and this may answer why its working locally but not in production. If you are using nginx, adjust your config file like so:

The Nginx configuration ensures that when a request is proxied from Nginx to your Node.js application, essential headers (like the original client IP address) and connection details are passed through.

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001; //your port
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

In your express backend add the following line:

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
```

By setting app.set('trust proxy', 1); in your Express app, you're telling Express to trust the first reverse proxy it sees. This is necessary because when you're behind a reverse proxy (like Nginx), client-specific data like IP address and, crucially, secure cookie handling can be lost unless you inform Express to trust the headers it gets from the proxy.

Ensuring cookies are set with the correct attributes, especially when dealing with cross-domain requests, is critical. The SameSite and Secure attributes help in making sure cookies are only sent over HTTPS and are available for cross-site requests.

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  proxy: true,
  store: storeSessions,
  cookie: {
          secure: true, // Set to true if you're using HTTPS
          httpOnly: true,
          maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // 1 day
          sameSite: "none",
        },
}));
```